# Swap values in array of class instances

Tags: c#, arrays, class, instance

```
public class Item{ some variables and methods }
public Item[] stash = new Item[50];

stash[a] = new Item();
stash[a].somevar = somevalue;
public Item it1 = stash[a];

stash[b] = new Item();
stash[b].somevar = someothervalue;
public Item it2 = stash[b];
```

I would like to swap content of **stash[a]** and **stash[b]** using only **it1** and **it2** because happens in a different chunk of code where I dont have access to **a** and **b** values anymore.

I have little experience with C# so I struggle to understand how it handles array of class instances.

Comment: So you have `stash` and `it1` and `it2` and you want to swap `it1` and `it2` around in `stash`?

Comment: You can't swap what you don't know, in this case you don't know the indexes

Comment: @Chris Yes, that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't swap what you don't know, in this case you don't know the indexes.

But you could search the indexes if you have both instances:

```
int indexOfIt1 = Array.FindIndex(stash, i => object.ReferenceEquals(i, it1));
int indexOfIt2 = Array.FindIndex(stash, i => object.ReferenceEquals(i, it2));
stash[indexOfIt2] = it1;
stash[indexOfIt1] = it2;
```

This checks if both are the same reference, if they are just *equal*(so equal property values) you should override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` and use `Array.IndexOf`. If you have multiple equal/same references this will replace arbitrary(the first).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. Just to clarify: if all items in stash are generated by `new` key word and/or swapping by this method, there shouldnt be any duplicate references, right?